# How can I use Redux to store my user authentication (token)?

Tags: redux

I developed a chrome extension where I am linking the login with the website.

I am using JWT tokens to authentication the user. So, I am storing these tokens in local storage and cookies. But, I don't want to store it in the local/session/cookies of the browser to call APIs. I browsed and got the Redux library.

How can I use redux to avoid storing my tokens in the local/session/cookies?

Any sample code snippet will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Redux doesn't (by itself) retain state between browser refreshes, so if the user reloads the browser, he'll essentially be logged out. This isn't very user friendly, or desirable in general.

You unfortunately will have to use some sort of persistent storage like local/session/cookie-store. Redux doesn't do that for you - Redux is just a library to help you manage state in a structured manner.

You can use Redux to somewhat hide the usage of the local, session or cookie store, but you will still be using it "behind the curtain".

Depending on the lifetime of your token, and how well versed you are in preventing XSS, I suggest storing the JWT token in a http-only, secure cookie. This will prevent malicious people from stealing the tokens using XSS.

Comment: Thank you @Nikolaj for the detail explaination. This is what I was looking for. It helped me a lot.